# Need to fix div when scrolling but when footer will display then div should not be fixed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a div I'm doing `position:fixed` when scrolling from top this is working fine but when footer will display then this div should not be fixed.

How can i do this?

**Div should not be overlap with footer.**

My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    background:#FFF;
}
div#mainContent {
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
}
div#sideBar {
    width:130px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
}
.clear { 
    clear:both; 
}
div#sticker {
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px 0;
    background:#AAA;
    width:190px;
    height:400px;
}
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
   
}

footer{background:red; padding:65px;  text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mainContent">
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
  </div>
  <div id="sideBar">Some content here 
    <!--Some content in your right column/sidebar-->
    <div id="sticker">...This is scroll here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

ThankYou!

Comment: I think you have a misconception on what s.position() does. It does not give you the position of the element inside the page, it gives you the css "position" value, in this case { left:"number", top:"number" } so you are trying to compare windowpos ( A number) with a css property. Working on a possible solution rn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you've to Apply both css and js , to achieve the right result :

First apply `position:relative` to your  wrapper (in order to place sticker at bottom by using bottom and positon absolute) ,

Then Add a class that set `postion:absolute` to the sticker ,

After you have to calculate outerHeight of your footer, and sitcker height ( to set it as the bottom value of ) ,

the condition should look like

```
if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
        
        if( windowpos + stickerHeight > footerTop ) {
          s.addClass("stick-bottom");
          s.removeClass("stick");
          s.css("bottom", footerHeight );
        }
        else {
          s.removeClass("stick-bottom");
          s.addClass("stick");
        }
        
} else {
        s.removeClass("stick-bottom"); 
        s.removeClass("stick");         
}
```

Checko below snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();  
    
    var footerHeight = $("footer").outerHeight();
    var footerTop = $("footer").position().top
    
    var stickerHeight = $("#sticker").outerHeight();
    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        
        console.log(windowpos + stickerHeight , "-" , footerTop)
        
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            
            if( windowpos + stickerHeight > footerTop ) {
              s.addClass("stick-bottom");
              s.removeClass("stick");
              s.css("bottom", footerHeight );
            }
            else {
              s.removeClass("stick-bottom");
              s.addClass("stick");
            }
            
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick-bottom"); 
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
            
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    background:#FFF;
    
    position:relative;  /*  added  */
}
div#mainContent {
    width:160px;
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
}
div#sideBar {
    width:130px;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:30px;
    float:left;
}
.clear { 
    clear:both; 
}
div#sticker {
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px 0;
    background:#AAA;
    width:190px;
    height:400px;
}

.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;  
}

.stick-bottom { /*  added  */
    position:absolute !important;/*  added  */
}/*  added  */

footer{background:red; padding:65px;  text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mainContent">
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
      some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
       some content here <br />
  </div>
  <div id="sideBar">Some content here 
    <!--Some content in your right column/sidebar-->
    <div id="sticker">...This is scroll here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if footer is now visible in view or not. Based on that, you will remove the `stick` class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s = $("#sticker");
  var pos = s.position();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = windowpos + $(window).height();
    var footerTop = $("footer").offset().top;
    var isFooterVisible = ((footerTop <= docViewBottom) && (footerTop >= windowpos))

    if (windowpos >= pos.top && !isFooterVisible) {
      s.addClass("stick");
    } else if (isFooterVisible) {
      s.removeClass("stick");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  background: #FFF;
}

div#mainContent {
  width: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}

div#sideBar {
  width: 130px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

div#sticker {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: #AAA;
  width: 190px;
  height: 400px;
}

.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

footer {
  background: red;
  padding: 65px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mainContent">
    some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br
    /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br /> some content here <br />
  </div>
  <div id="sideBar">Some content here
    <!--Some content in your right column/sidebar-->
    <div id="sticker">...This is scroll here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the overlapping, then you can try to use sticky position instead of fixed. Here's an example achieved with flexbox and no javascript:

CSS:

```
 <style>
      div#wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 500px;
        background: #fff;
        /* This is just to show that it will not overlap when you scroll down */
        min-height: 500vh;
      }

      div.inner {
        display: flex;
      }

      div#mainContent {
        width: 160px;
        padding: 20px;
      }

      div#sideBar {
        width: 130px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-left: 30px;
      }

      .clear {
        clear: both;
      }

      div#sticker {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        background: #aaa;
        width: 190px;
        height: 400px;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }

      footer {
        background: red;
        padding: 65px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="inner">
        <div id="mainContent">
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
          some content here <br />
        </div>
        <div id="sideBar">
          Some content here
          <!--Some content in your right column/sidebar-->
          <div id="sticker">...This is scroll here</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <footer>Footer</footer>
    </div>
```